# Getting protractor promise, variables and results synchronized

Tags: javascript, protractor

Okay, I have this piece of code I'm trying, and failing, at writing. What I want to do is to make sure an index that is passed to a function is within the bounds of available elements on a page. And, if it is, pass back an element reference.

Suppose I have the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>First row</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

So, I've got this function:

```
function getRow(index) {
   // get count of rows.
   var count = $$('li').count();

   // Ensure a parameter has been passed.
   if (!index) {
      throw Error("A parameter must be supplied for function getRow. Valid values are 0 through " + count-1);
   }
   // Ensure the parameter is within bounds
   if (index < 0 || index >= count) {
      throw Error("The parameter, " + index + ", is not within the bounds of 0 through " + count-1);
   }

   return $$('li').get(index);
}
```

The above will fail because count is not really count, but a promise.

So, I've tried modifying it in various ways.  The one I thought would be successful is as follows:

```
// get count of rows.
var count;
$$('li').count().then(function(c) { count = c; });
```

or

```
// get count of rows.
var count = $$('li').count().then(function(c) { return c; });
```

I've gotten frustrated and tried to throw the whole if block within the thenable function, but it won't "see" index.

*(Every time I think I've figured this out, I don't. Thank you for any and all assistance!)*

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestion below I tried modifying my code to:

```
function getRow(index) {
  //get count of rows.
  var count = $$('li').count().then(function(c) {
    return function() {
      return c;
    }
  });

  protractor.promise.all(count).then(function(count) {
    // Ensure a parameter has been passed.
    if (!index) {
      throw Error("A parameter must be supplied for function getRow. Valid values are 0 through " + count-1);
    }
    // Ensure the parameter is within bounds
    if (index < 0 || index >= count) {
      throw Error("The parameter, " + index + ", is not within the bounds of 0 through " + count-1);
    }
  });

  return $$('li').get(index);
}
```

But it failed because, within the `protractor.promise.all().then()` block, `index` is undefined.  Also, in the error message, I don't even get a value for count.

```
> getRow(0);
A parameter must be supplied for function getRow. Valid values are 0 through
```

Comment: Maybe cause you're calling `index` on a single object rather than an array (you're missing `.all` in your locator)?  Does `var count = element.all(by.css(...))` help?  Then use a .all function such as `.each` or `.map` ? [source](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each)

Comment: You're right. I was trying to avoid using the shorthand $$, but failed on the conversion. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use the javascript closures in order to achive it.

Try it:

```
var count = element(by.css('li')).count().then(function(c){
    return function(){
        return c
    }   
});

var value = count();
```

Your value should be in the "value" variable.

PS: I don't have a protractor environment to test this code now

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: count is not a function`.

Comment: I've added an update to my question above using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it.

```
function getRow(index) {
    var count = $$('li').count();

    var test = function(index, count) {
        // Ensure a parameter has been passed.
        if (index == undefined) {
            throw Error("A parameter must be supplied for function getRow. Valid values are 0 through " + count-1);
        }
        // Ensure the parameter is within bounds
       if (index < 0 || index >= count) {
           throw Error("The parameter, " + index + ", is not within the  bounds of 0 through " + count-1);
        }
    });

    count.then(function(count) {
        test(index, count);
    }

    return $$('li').get(index);
}
```

I'm not sure why this works and my previous attempt didn't.  Well, other than I abstracted the function and allowed myself to pass in the index in a clean manner.

Comment: What I probably did was create a closure.  (Just as flaviomeira10 suggested.)